# Why is my HR not displaying on a separate line?

Tags: html

I've got this HTML:

```
<article class="smallCaps">
    Cap Anson <span><em>my</em></span> outboard<br />
    Anyway...the reign in Spain falls mainly on the common folk<br/>
    Note: This is a big secret. Don't tell <em>them</em>
</article>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<hr />
```

...but the HR displays to the right of "Don't tell *them*" instead of on a separate line.

Here's the CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .smallCaps {
        font-variant: small-caps;
        font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
    }
    .comicSansLarge {
        font-size: 32px;
        font-family: "Comic Sans", Consolas, serif;
        color: hsl(30, 100%, 50%);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: if you run that in JSFiddle, it renders below the content.(chrome)

Comment: My *guess* would be that the `<article>` is floated left, but without seeing a working example, it's hard to say.

Comment: e.g. http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/nEcCA

Comment: Could not reproduce: http://jsfiddle.net/VGXG2/ You must be missing something else in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your css:

```
hr {
  clear:both;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible  cause would be that the article is floated. like this:

http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/jyngu

Something in your CSS is causing it but it's impossible to say what it is without seeing your css.